# Is there any benefit to marking java objects final that are effectively final?

Tags: java, immutability

I have an immutable object that doesn't have its fields or class marked as final.  I could do this, but is there really any benefit to doing this? I could see it saving the compiler a little bit of time figuring things out, but I can't see it being "worth" it (other then the fact that it will make future developers rethink doing something to the object to make it mutable).

Comment: Documentation is always a good reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the points you make (future developer modifying the fields being a very sensible one, another one is that someone could subclass your class and make it mutable), explicitly marking the fields as final provides you with visibility guarantees in a multi threaded environment.

Take this class - it is effectively immutable:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int i;
    public SomeClass(int i) { this.i = i; }
    public int getI() { return this.i; }
}
```

In a multi-threaded environment, it is possible that a thread T1 creates a `SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(1);` and that another thread T2 reads `sc.getI()` and sees 0.

If `i` is made final, this can not happen any more (assuming you don't let `this` escape during construction, as explained in the quote below).

Reference: [JLS #17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) - emphasis mine

> final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. [...]
>   The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, **that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields**.

Comment: subclasses can't mutate if the field is private

Comment: @Bohemian Not sure what you mean.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. A subclass can't "make it mutable" if the fields are private. Also, even if the fields are final, if the accessor methods aren't `final`, a subclass you just override getters/setters to make a `final` field effectively mutable by implementing its own shadowed field. Also, even final fields can be different in different threads if you allow `this` to "escape" during construction (by passing `this` to some method in the constructor *before* the field is set)

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry I had not understood you were referring to that part of my answer. Yes that's a good point. Agreed with your second point too, and clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It serves to show your intentions and not for someone to make it mutable by mistake.
Addionally marking a method as final *may* become inline gaining performance advantage.
Also marking the reference objects of a class as `final` forces the constructor to be atomic.
Finally marking the class as `final` stops inheritence. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Making the field `final` is more about showing the *intention* of the code.

Unless you make the getter methods `final`, your class isn't immutable. Consider:

```
public class MyClass {

   private final int num;

   public int getNum() {
       return num;
   }
}

public class MySubClass extends MyClass {
   private int num;

   public int getNum() {
       return num;
   }

   public void setNum(int i) {
       num = i;
   }
}
```

The subclass has completely overridden the field, making it mutable. All you have to do is cast an instance of `MyClass` to `MySubClass` to get access to the setter. Even without the setter, the subclass could change its `num` field in another method.

Assuming the field is private, it doesn't matter if the field is `final`: You need to either make your class `final`, or make your getter `final`.

Note also that even with all the code protection you like, using reflection other classes can still cut through everything and mutate your field.

Answer (score 0):

First, a `final` field is something very different from a `final` class. A final field cannot be changed. The `final` modifier on classes means that no other class is allowed to inherit from that class, but has no implications for the fields at all.

That being said, having fields marked final does indeed allow the compiler to do some optimizations. How big the effect of those are depends a lot. If you have no performance issues in your program, it's probably not worth it.

But in terms of design, marking things final if they are intended to be final is useful so nobody who's using your class can inadvertently break something. So overall, if you have something that you by design don't want to change later on, make it final.